# Could not create Convex Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment i´m creating a custom Mesh. It will be a procedural Planet with high detailed System. My problem is that when i try to create a Convex Mesh Collider i get an Error, actually dont know how to fix it.

---

```
Couldn't create a Convex Mesh from source mesh "MeshName" within the maximum polygons limit (256). The partial hull will be used. Consider simplifying your mesh.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

---

In the Unity forum i have read it is a Unity bug.

**Do you guys know how to fix it?**

I need a Mesh Collider because i want to implement Mountains and i need a Player to collide with the planet.

**Maybe you know some other Solutions i can use for this instead of a high Poly MeshCollider?**

Thank you for your answers Stackoverflow Community.
Best Wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

It gives you an error because your mesh exceeds the 256 polygons limit for mesh colliders. Generally speaking, using a mesh collider is not a good practice, it's not efficient in the physics engine. Instead try using other colliders like BoxCollider, SphereCollider, and CapsuleCollider. or maybe combine some of these simpler colliders to create your desired shape.